# Expand content background and position footer at bottom of page.

Tags: css, sticky-footer

i'm using the method listed [here](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/) to create a sticky footer. This works great, however my content divs above it have a semi transparent background, and are in turn placed on another background. You can see the site I am working on [here](http://www.thirdsectorfilms.com)

what I want to do is to have a sticky footer, but I also need the transparent background in the content div to expand to reach the footer.

Thanks.

Comment: just figured this out using [link](http://codecamel.com/fullheight) this tutorial